# Taxonomy Access module with role

Tags: users, taxonomy-terms

After install [Taxonomy Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) and access the basic admin content page "admin/content"
with an admin role called "publisher" which has the authority to administer the content the page does not show any content at all as in the attached image[image]
even i created admin views to show specific content and it works well with the "publisher" role, any reason why the basic admin page is empty !?

Comment: Did you rebuild the permissions? /admin/reports/status/rebuild

Comment: yes definitely, i don't think its the problem with the module its the problem of the page "admin/content" itself because i installed similar module and after rebuild the permission it caused the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was from the custom relation i made to the Administration: Nodes (Content),
now it works after removing the unneeded relations.